# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender.<init>(Lorg/apache/log4j/Layout;)

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a maven project with jdk: 1.8, spring-boot: 1.5.4.RELEASE, spring: 4.3.9.RELEASE, and some vendor dependencies. The project builds and runs but when I access resources used by vendor packages, I get following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender.<init>(Lorg/apache/log4j/Layout;)V
    at bkLogPkg.SingletonLog.<init>(SingletonLog.java:19) ~[VendorComLib.jar:na]
    at Vendor.ConnectionBasket.<init>(ConnectionBasket.java:31) ~[VendorServices.jar:na]
    at Vendor.ConnectionBasketInterface.Loader(ConnectionBasketInterface.java:450) ~[VendorServices.jar:na]
    at Vendor.ConnectionBasketInterface.<init>(ConnectionBasketInterface.java:251) ~[VendorServices.jar:na]

...
```

It's trying to call method from Vendor jar file to log4j 1.2.14.jar file, but it's unable to do it. I have added vendor dependencies in pom.xml file.

pom.xml: 
 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>angular2-spring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>angular2-spring</name>
<description>Angular 2 application with Spring 4</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.2.14</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Vendor dependencies from Local Repository -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Vendor</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Vendor</groupId>
        <artifactId>VendorServiceAuth</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Vendor</groupId>
        <artifactId>VendorServices</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Vendor</groupId>
        <artifactId>VendorComLib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Vendor</groupId>
        <artifactId>VendorHeaderClass</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue today. It cost me several hours to find the reason.

You just have a **conflict** with your log4j jar.

The quick fix for this is :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If you really need log4j, then add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can check [log4j-over-slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j) to know the detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issues and all of mine were solved by making sure the version I was using was the most updated and that is is compatible with the rest of the code. With your problem, it looks as if the .jar is specifically built to be compatible so I doubt that's the issue. Only things I can think of given the information at hand is:

1.) Try making sure all .jar's being used are newest version. (Sometimes if your other .jar's are not completely updated, they can throw errors/exceptions when trying to access a method from a .jar that is a version ahead.)

2.) If "1" doesn't do it, try using a dependency import function in an IDE. I have had many occurrences where Maven was just causing odd errors from IDE compatibility. Importing all .jar's from a "Dependency" menu could also help.

Comment: I have the jar imported in Dependency menu and I cannot update the log4j jar because my Vendor jars are dependent on older version of log4j

Comment: Only thing I can think of if that's the case is make sure that the version of log4j that you're using is the correct older version. Just be aware that outdated .jar's are prone to problems like this. If this is not the issue, I'd suggest trying to find a replacement for the vendor .jar's for something updated to the current version.

Comment: Well, it is the correct version and as you can see above I'm using log4j jar file provided by vendor, which works in my console project but when I use that in web application it fails. I manually have to include that file in my project build path to work properly. Which I don't understand, I have that file in pom.xml which adds jar file in project build path under maven library but it doesn't work but when I add the jar file manually to build path, it works!